# push only unique values into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, servicenow

> not able to check the unique values  log showing all values getting
> added to the array

.

```
var moveToReady = [];       
 var topLinesRecords = new GlideRecord('x_snc_ms_dynamics_d365_queue');
    topLinesRecords.addEncodedQuery('root_element_sys_id=03133e1a1bfe6410f8ca0e16624bcba7');
    topLinesRecords.orderByDesc('sys_created_on');
    topLinesRecords.query();
    while(topLinesRecords.next()){

gs.info(' first record : ' + topLinesRecords.number);

    if(moveToReady.indexOf(topLinesRecords.getValue('object_sys_id')) == -1){
        moveToReady.push(topLinesRecords.getValue('object_sys_id'));
         }

gs.info('array.  : ' + moveToReady);
        updateRecordtoFail(topLinesRecords);
        }
```

Comment: Are you adding `sysId` in the array and Do you want unique `sysId in that array?`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Set** structure from ES6 to make your code faster and more readable:

```
// Create Set
this.items = new Set();

add(item) {
    this.items.add(item);

    // Set to array
    console.log([...this.items]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use `array.includes`

```
if (!moveToReady.includes(topLinesRecords.getValue('object_sys_id'))){
  moveToReady.push(topLinesRecords.getValue('object_sys_id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, some tips to get unique values on ServiceNow:
-GlideRecord has a "getUniqueValue" method
(URL: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-platform-administration/page/administer/table-administration/concept/c_UniqueRecordIdentifier.html)

-You can search on your Script Includes a OOB method/function to get only unique values. Search for "utils". Every instance has this, maybe "ArrayUtils".

Hope this information helped!